# SELECT value from another table with similar date pgSQL

Tags: postgresql

Please advise proper solution for:

```
    CREATE TABLE test.rate
(
    date date NOT NULL,
    rate numeric(10,4) NOT NULL,
)

CREATE TABLE test.purchase
(
    prod_id text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    import_id text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    exw_price_usd numeric(10,2),
    exw_price_eur numeric(10,2),
    import_exp numeric(10,2),
    stock_price numeric(10,2),
    qty numeric(10,0),
    date date NOT NULL
)

BEGIN

SELECT rate
FROM test.rate
WHERE test.rate (date) = test.purchase (date);

UPDATE purchase
SET exw_price_eur=exw_price_usd/test.rate;
RETURN NEW exw_price_eur; 

END;
```

ERROR:  function test.rate(date) does not exist
LINE 3:     WHERE test.rate (date) = test.purchase (date);

we need to choose value of rate from table test.rate which corresponds with date value in table test.purchase

For example...

test.rate
date '2020-10-10'
rate '1.2345'

test.purchase
exw_price_usd '30'
date '2020-10-10'

return calculation 30/1.2345

Comment: This is not valid SQL. Please provide sample data and desired results, otherwise it's hard to really guess what you are trying to do.

Comment: this is a part of function to convert price in USD to EUR at exact day.
one table test.rate has two columns date and rate and value of rate has to be used in converting USD price to EUR price.
As soon value rate with proper date is selected it will be used for this conversion.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking text tables. ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Answer (score 0):

Partially solved this issue, but anyway don't have result as a new record in the exw_price_eur column

```
BEGIN
SELECT rate
    FROM test.rate
    INNER JOIN test.purchase
    ON purchase.date=rate.date; 
UPDATE test.purchase
SET purchase.exw_price_eur=purchase.exw_price_usd/rate.rate;
RETURN NEW.exw_price_eur;
END;
```

and when process

```
INSERT INTO test.purchase(
exw_price_usd, date)
VALUES (42, '10-10-2020');
```

ERROR:  query has no destination for result data.

Please advise

Answer (score 0):

Proper solution

```
BEGIN
UPDATE test.purchase pr
SET exw_price_eur = exw_price_usd/e.rate
FROM test.eurusd  e
WHERE e.date=pr.date;
RETURN NEW.exw_price_eur;
END
```